# fputs or fprintf not writing into a file for strings

Tags: c, file

Why `fputs()` or `fprintf()` are not writing into the `file.txt` for `%s`? I tried both functions but they don't seem to write into the file. However, when using the same functions for `%d`, it does work currently. As for the expected output versus what currently happens, please find below an example when choosing option 1 in the program, and entering a square side of 2.

Currently happening:

```
1
2
4
8
```

Expected output:

```
You have chosen option: 1
The side of the square is: 2
The square area is: 4
The square perimeter is: 8
```

Any ideas as to what may be causing this? Thank you!

**N.b.** This code is for learning purposes, so you may find inconsistencies in the way I work with variables (i.e. passing by reference or value). Please disregard that.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#define PI 3.14

void square_functions (int side, int *square_perimeter, int *square_area);
float circle_functions (float radius, float * area_circle, float * circumference, FILE *fich);

int main() 
{ 

    float radius, area_circle, circumference;
    int side, square_area, square_perimeter, choice;
    FILE *fich; /* esto como variable global penaliza! */
    fich=fopen("file.txt","w");

    while (1) 
    {
    printf("Enter 1 to calculate the square\n"); 
    printf("Enter 2 to calculate the circumference\n");
    printf("Enter your option:\n"); 
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "You have chosen option:");
    fprintf(fich,"%d\n",choice);

    switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1: 
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%d", &side);
            fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "The side of the square is:");
            fprintf(fich,"%d\n",side);
            if(side > 0)
            {
                square_functions (side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
                printf("\nSquare area: %d", square_area);
                printf("\nSquare perimeter: %d\n", square_perimeter);
                fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "The square area is:");
                fprintf(fich,"%d\n", square_area);
                fputs("The square perimeter is",fich);
                fprintf(fich,"%d\n", square_perimeter);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            } 
        break;

        case 2: 
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%f", &radius);

            if(radius > 0)
            {
                circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference, fich);  
                printf("Circle area: %f", area_circle);
                printf("circumference: %f", circumference);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
        break;
        }
    }
fclose(fich);
return 0;
}

void square_functions (int side, int *square_perimeter, int *square_area)
{       
        *square_perimeter = side * 4;
        *square_area = side * side;
}

float circle_functions (float radius, float * area_circle, float * circumference, FILE *fich) 
{
        *area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
        *circumference = 2 * PI * radius;
        fputs("The area of the circle is",fich); 
        fprintf(fich,"%f\n",*area_circle);
        fputs("The circumference is",fich);
        fprintf(fich,"%f\n",*circumference);
        return 0;       
}
```

Comment: Please specify the expected output and actual output of **both** output streams (`stdout` and `fich`). Also, please specify the exact input that was entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreasWenzel comments I have added below the final pieces of code that work; first version using `fclose(fich);` and second one using `fflush(fich);`.

`fclose(fich);` version: the file is being closed every time is opened to write in it.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI 3.14

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area);
void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference);

int main() 
{ 

    double radius, area_circle, circumference, side, square_area, square_perimeter;
    int choice;
    FILE *fich;

    while (1) 
    {
    printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square"); 
    printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
    printf("\nEnter your option:"); 
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fich,"%s", "\n\nThe option chosen is: ");
    fprintf(fich,"%d\n",choice);
    fclose(fich);

    switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &side);
            fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe side of the square is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",side);
            if(side > 0)
            {
            square_functions (side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
            printf("\nSquare area: %lf", square_area);
            printf("\nSquare perimeter: %lf\n", square_perimeter);  
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_area);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square perimeter is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_perimeter);
            fclose(fich);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            } 
        break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &radius);
            fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe radius of the circle is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",radius);         
            if(radius > 0)
            {
            circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference);       
            printf("\nCircle area: %lf\n", area_circle);
            printf("\nCircumference: %lf\n", circumference);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circle area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",area_circle);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circumference is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",circumference);
            fclose(fich);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
        break;
        }
    }
return 0;
}

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area)
{       
        *square_perimeter = side * 4;
        *square_area = side * side;
}

void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference) 
{
        *area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
        *circumference = 2 * PI * radius;   
}
```

`fflush(fich);` version: the buffer is flushed immediately before the switch statement and once immediately after the switch statement (as the last statement of the while loop).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI 3.14

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area);
void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference);

int main() 
{ 

    double radius, area_circle, circumference, side, square_area, square_perimeter;
    int choice;
    FILE *fich;
    fich = fopen("file.txt","a+");

    while (1) 
    {
    printf("\nEnter 1 to calculate the square"); 
    printf("\nEnter 2 to calculate the circumference");
    printf("\nEnter your option:"); 
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    fprintf(fich,"%s", "\n\nThe option chosen is: ");
    fprintf(fich,"%d\n",choice);
    fflush( fich );

    switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
            scanf("%lf", &side);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe side of the square is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",side);
            if(side > 0)
            {
            square_functions (side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
            printf("\nSquare area: %lf", square_area);
            printf("\nSquare perimeter: %lf\n", square_perimeter);  
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_area);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe square perimeter is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf", square_perimeter);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            } 
        break;

        case 2:
            printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius fo the circle: ");
            scanf("%lf", &radius);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe radius of the circle is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",radius);         
            if(radius > 0)
            {
            circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference);       
            printf("\nCircle area: %lf\n", area_circle);
            printf("\nCircumference: %lf\n", circumference);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circle area is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",area_circle);
            fprintf(fich,"%s", "\nThe circumference is: ");
            fprintf(fich,"%lf",circumference);
            }
            else
            {
            printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
            }
        break;
        }
    fflush( fich );
    }
return 0;
}

void square_functions (double side, double *square_perimeter, double *square_area)
{       
        *square_perimeter = side * 4;
        *square_area = side * side;
}

void circle_functions (double radius, double *area_circle, double *circumference) 
{
        *area_circle = PI * radius * radius;
        *circumference = 2 * PI * radius;   
}
```

Comment: It looks like this code still has an infinite loop, and the calls to `fopen()` and `fclose()` must match. (they do not here.)  After your first time in the loop, `fich` will be closed, and not accessible until re-opened. Also, `case 2:` still does not write to the file.  Is this your updated working code?

Comment: @ryyker: Actually, `case2` does write to the file, but only inside the function call `circle_functions`.

Comment: If you really want to keep your infinite loop, I suggest you use `fflush` instead of `fclose`. That way, your will be still able to write to the file afterwards.

Comment: Hi @AndreasWenzel! After reviewing your comments  I have cleaned up the above answer. I am opening and closing the file every time I write on it. Not sure if it is very efficient, resources wise but at least it does work properly now. Please let me know what you think! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @ryyker just FYI for you too. Check above last comment I made. Thank you!

Comment: @Henry: Using `fflush` would be cleaner and better for performance. But if you don't mind opening and closing a file every time, then you can of course do it that way, too.

Comment: @Henry: I like it that you removed the output from inside the function `circle_functions`. It was inconsistent that the function `square_functions` had no direct output whereas the function `circle_functions` was calling output functions directly.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you for your answer! :-) Would you mind showing me how the code would end up being if `fflush` was used? Thank you again for all your help! :-)

Comment: @Henry: You could call `fflush( fich );` after every call to `fprintf( fitch, ... );` in order to always be sure that the latest output gets flushed immediately. However, that would be inefficient. Therefore, it would be best to only call `fflush` immediately after the last call to `fprintf` before a longer period of no more output occuring, for example because the program is waiting for input from `scanf`. I think it would be best to call `fflush` twice, once immediately before the `switch` statement and once immediately after the `switch` statement (as the last statement of the while loop).

Comment: Awesome @AndreasWenzel Just added the version with `fflush( fich );` in the above answer. Thanks very much for all your help on this one man!! :-)

Comment: @Henry: It seems that you removed all calls to `fclose`, but not the calls to `fopen`. This means you are calling `fopen` three times on the same file, without ever closing it. This may cause `fich` to be `NULL` if the first call to `fopen` succeeds, but a subsequent call fails, because the file is already open. Therefore, I suggest you call `fopen` only once at the start of your program.

Comment: @Henry: Opening the same file several times without ever closing them may work on your operating system. However, it may fail on other operating systems. Therefore, I don't recommend it.

Comment: hey @AndreasWenzel just corrected the code according to your comments. Thank you very much for your effort in ensuring this was done properly. Very much appreciated man!! :-)

Comment: @Henry: Yes, the code looks good now. Of course, normally, you should always have a matching `fclose` for every call to `fopen`. But that doesn't make sense when you have an infinite loop. The cleanest solution to this would be to provide a menu option for the user to end the program, which exits the loop. That way, the loop would no longer be infinite. After exiting the loop, you could then call `fclose`.

Comment: Understood @AndreasWenzel Thank you for all your help!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're not closing the file.  Note: You have `fclose(fich);`, but it's unreachable.  Add a third condition, such as the following, at it should work:

```
case 3:
    fclose(fich);
    return 0;
```

An alternative would be to not use an infinite loop (`while(1)`) and use a condition instead.  For example:

```
bool run = true;
while(run)
{
    ...
    case 3:
        run = false;
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer @Fiddling Bits! :-) What I don't understand is why it wasn't an issue when printing integers but now it is for strings. Thank you!

Comment: When you call `fprintf` it may stay in a buffer until flushed.  `\n` will flush the buffer but it looks like you may be using it incorrectly (`fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "You have chosen option:");`) as pointed out by @PiGuy.  I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: With me, `stdout` is **line buffered** whereas `fich` (the file stream) is **fully buffered**. However, I believe that is platform-dependant. I guess that is why `\n` has no effect on buffering.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try `fprintf(fich,"The square area is:\n");`

Comment: thank you @PiGuy thank you for your quick answer. I am not really getting it to work either with the above suggestion. Any other ideas?

Comment: Although `fprintf(fich,"The square area is:\n");` may be simpler and more efficient than writing `fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "The square area is:");`, it seems just as correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as is, is fairly complete, but requires a few adjustments

- Requires a way to exit,
- In the second `case` (circles) the function `printf()` is used as opposed to `fprintf()`.
- `fclose()` is never accessed due to infinite loop

The following addresses these, by using a `boolean` variable `running` as a flag to run, and a third `case` to access it to exit, and adds the `fprintf` function in the second case, and `opens/closes` file each iteration:

```
#define FILENAME "file.txt" 

int main(void) 
{ 
    float radius, area_circle, circumference;
    int side, square_area, square_perimeter, choice;
    BOOL running = TRUE;
    FILE *fich; /* esto como variable global penaliza! */
    //create file for write:
    fich=fopen(FILENAME,"w");//test before using
    if(fich)
    {
        fprintf(fich, "Beginning of file:\n\n");
        fclose(fich);
    }

    while (running) 
    {
        printf("Enter 1 to calculate the square\n"); 
        printf("Enter 2 to calculate the circumference\n");
        printf("Enter 3 to quit program\n");        
        printf("Enter your option:\n"); 
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        fprintf(fich,"%d\n",choice);

        switch (choice) 
        { 
        case 1: 
            fich=fopen(FILENAME,"a");//test before using
            if(fich)
            {
                printf("Please enter the side of the square: ");
                scanf("%d", &side);
                fprintf(fich,"%d\n",side);
                if(side > 0)
                {
                    square_functions (side, &square_perimeter, &square_area);
                    printf("\nSquare area: %d", square_area);
                    printf("\nSquare perimeter: %d\n", square_perimeter);
                    fprintf(fich,"%s\n", "The square area is: %d\n");
                    fprintf(fich,"The perimeter is: %d\n", square_perimeter);
                }               
                else
                {
                    printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
                }
                fclose(fich);
            }
            break;

        case 2: 
            fich=fopen(FILENAME,"a");//test before using
            if(fich)
            {
                printf("\n\nPlease enter the radius of the circle: ");
                scanf("%f", &radius);

                if(radius > 0)
                {
                    circle_functions (radius, &area_circle, &circumference, fich);  
                    printf("Circle area: %f", area_circle);
                    printf("circumference: %f", circumference);
                    fprintf(fich, "Circle area: %f", area_circle);
                    fprintf(fich, "circumference: %f", circumference);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("The value is invalid, the operation has been cancelled");
                }
                fclose(fich);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            running = FALSE;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your anwer @ryyker! :-) I am getting these errors: https://screencast.com/t/yb6DUWeBU Could you maybe give it another go to complete this? Thank you!!

Comment: @Henry -   I did not add in the code that you already had working :) All the changes are in the `main()` function.  So you need to include your header includes, the function prototypes, and `#defines`.  Also, my BOOL may need to be changed to `bool` for your environment, same for `TRUE`

Comment: Understood. Thank you, Ryyker!

Answer (score 1):

When I run the program on Microsoft Windows, the output to `stdout` works, but not the output to `fich`. The problem is that (at least with me), `stdout` is [line buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/12149471), whereas `fich` is fully buffered. Since you never call `fclose` (because it is outside the infinite loop), the buffer of `fich` never gets flushed.

To fix this problem, you can either explicitly flush the buffer with `fflush( fich );` or you can implicitly flush the buffer, by ensuring that `fclose` gets called (for example by exiting the loop).

Alternatively, you can disable buffering completely, by calling `setbuf( fich, NULL);` Please note that this line must appear immediately after the call to `fopen`. See the [documentation on the function `setbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) for further information. However, this should normally not be done, because buffering can be important for performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Andreas Wenzel. This helped to achieve the final code that worked! :)